# Deleting Empty Tables From html file

Tags: html, python-2.7

I have a HTML file containing Tables containing SQL O/p's. But after every desired table , i am also getting a Blank table which i intent on removing.

The blank table is coded as -

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
<thead>
<tr style="text-align: right;">
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And it looks like [image: Empty Table Snapshot]

I was thinking of using BeautifulSOup,But after going a bit, I was stranded on what to do now.
I had thought of removing the above piece of code from html but beautifulsoup is mostly used for web-scraping/Parsing and here I got stuck.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "final_output.html"
html=open(url)
soup = BS(html.read())
table = soup.findAll("table",{"class" : "dataframe"})
```

The HTML File is like - (showing partial file only)

```
2 Data classes with missing data (* Check last 5 days only) <table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>



<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>data_class</th>
      <th>missing_count</th>
      <th>expected_device_count</th>
      <th>expected_device_online</th>
      <th>missing_count_for_device_online</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table> Against ah_unit<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>



<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>data_class</th>
      <th>missing_count</th>
      <th>expected_device_count</th>
      <th>expected_device_online</th>
      <th>missing_count_for_device_online</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>3 How many devices have bad storageid's in tm_devicestorage<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>



<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>bad_storage_id_data_count</th>
      <th>bad_storage_id_data_count_last_week</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>4
(Continued)
```

I need to get rid of the empty tables present in the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming BeautifulSoup 4.7+.

You should be able to use selectors to identify tables that are not empty. In this example, we will use some special pseudo-classes: `:is()` which will simply allow us to group multiple selectors. `:has()` which will let us look ahead at a particular elements descendants, `:empty` (as specified in CSS level 4) which returns elements that have no children an no text (except whitespace), and lastly `:not()` which looks for elements that do not match.

- https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#:not
- https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#:has
- https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#:empty
- https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#:is

We will find the empty tables with this selector: `table:not(:has(:is(th,td):not(:empty)))`

It looks for a `table` that does not have any descendants that are `th` or `td` and are not empty.

We remove the children in reverse order to make sure we don't accidentally remove something that has a child we later want to remove. Not necessarily needed here, but I do this out of habit.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>data_class</th>
      <th>missing_count</th>
      <th>expected_device_count</th>
      <th>expected_device_online</th>
      <th>missing_count_for_device_online</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table> Against ah_unit<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>data_class</th>
      <th>missing_count</th>
      <th>expected_device_count</th>
      <th>expected_device_online</th>
      <th>missing_count_for_device_online</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>3 How many devices have bad storageid's in tm_devicestorage<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>bad_storage_id_data_count</th>
      <th>bad_storage_id_data_count_last_week</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
for el in reversed(soup.select('table:not(:has(:is(th,td):not(:empty)))')):
    el.extract()

print(str(soup))
```

This leaves us with only the tables with content:

```
<html><head></head><body>                                                                                                                                                             

<table border="1" class="dataframe">                                                                                                                                                  
  <thead>                                                                                                                                                                             
    <tr style="text-align: right;">                                                                                                                                                   
      <th></th>                                                                                                                                                                       
      <th>date</th>                                                                                                                                                                   
      <th>data_class</th>                                                                                                                                                             
      <th>missing_count</th>                                                                                                                                                          
      <th>expected_device_count</th>                                                                                                                                                  
      <th>expected_device_online</th>                                                                                                                                                 
      <th>missing_count_for_device_online</th>                                                                                                                                        
    </tr>                                                                                                                                                                             
  </thead>                                                                                                                                                                            
  <tbody>                                                                                                                                                                             
  </tbody>                                                                                                                                                                            
</table> Against ah_unit                                                                                                                                                              

<table border="1" class="dataframe">                                                                                                                                                  
  <thead>                                                                                                                                                                             
    <tr style="text-align: right;">                                                                                                                                                   
      <th></th>                                                                                                                                                                       
      <th>date</th>                                                                                                                                                                   
      <th>data_class</th>                                                                                                                                                             
      <th>missing_count</th>                                                                                                                                                          
      <th>expected_device_count</th>                                                                                                                                                  
      <th>expected_device_online</th>                                                                                                                                                 
      <th>missing_count_for_device_online</th>                                                                                                                                        
    </tr>                                                                                                                                                                             
  </thead>                                                                                                                                                                            
  <tbody>                                                                                                                                                                             
  </tbody>                                                                                                                                                                            
</table>3 How many devices have bad storageid's in tm_devicestorage                                                                                                                   

<table border="1" class="dataframe">                                                                                                                                                  
  <thead>                                                                                                                                                                             
    <tr style="text-align: right;">                                                                                                                                                   
      <th></th>                                                                                                                                                                       
      <th>date</th>                                                                                                                                                                   
      <th>bad_storage_id_data_count</th>                                                                                                                                              
      <th>bad_storage_id_data_count_last_week</th>                                                                                                                                    
    </tr>                                                                                                                                                                             
  </thead>                                                                                                                                                                            
  <tbody>                                                                                                                                                                             
  </tbody>                                                                                                                                                                            
</table>                                                                                                                                                                              
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks @facelessuser, Your code does work and cleans the empty tables. But it also removes the Text and modifies the look of the script in certain ways. I have updated my original comment with a snapshot of how i want it to look . I will try to build on your idea. Whosoever finds solution to this issue will let the other know , here on this question. Thanks again for spending time to help me out. :)

Comment: @GolokeshPatra, what text is being removed? My solution doesn't alter text outside of the tables being removed. If you are talking about the non-essential whitespace differences, this is due to the parser being used. You can install https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/ and select it with the parser: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')` which does a better job at preserving non-essential whtiespace.

Comment: I've updated the solution to use htmllib in the example. Though for all intent and purposes, the solution itself answered the question. This adds the additional request to preserve non-essential whitespace (as possible by the available parsers).